# Google Map one Keyword search

Tags: php, seo

When searching for the company name "[EngineerBabu](https://www.google.co.in/#q=engineerbabu)" I am getting a result without the address
[image: searching EngineerBabu on google.co.in]

When searching for the company name "[EngineerBabu address](https://www.google.co.in/#q=engineerbabu+address)" I am getting a result with the address
[image: searching EngineerBabu address on google.co.in]

But when I search for "[MashinMedia](https://www.google.co.in/#q=mashinmedia)" on google.co.in without adding the address keyword I am getting the correct result without the address keyword
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I hope this is clear enough. you can check screenshot as well.

Comment: Question:- what changes should i do?  so that if people searching "engineerbabu" they will get address as well

Comment: This has to do with Googles search algorithm. You don't have much control over this. The point is that people who frequently search your address by using the keywords `EngineerBabu address` will eventually pull up the map. So to get a map when you search, people will have to search the keyword `EngineerBabu` then go to maps or something similar indicating to google they are trying to use that keyword mostly to get directions.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about Google Places :)

Check this out:
http://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/free-features/

You can create a free account.

Comment: This is a Google Plus Page.
You need to create a listing in Google Maps and add it to Google Places. Check the link above.
Google Places is different then Google Plus.